# What does "RAM R/W test failed" mean?

Tags: memory, bios

I had problems installing an operating system and booting my computer, so I disabled the system's "Intel® Rapid Boot BIOS" feature. Now, whenever I start the computer, I get a message telling me that my "RAM R/W test failed." What does that mean? Do I have to do anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@soandos is probably correct. Ignoring the problem does not make the problem go away. This is like the low oil level warning light in your car; you can put black tape over it, but that doesn't raise your oil level.

RAM these days is dirt cheap. You might want to consider just replacing it.

Your PC may *seem* to be running okay, but who knows what spurious bits are being erroneously written, possibly corrupting your data? Is you peace of mind worth it?

If you don't replace it, be sure to keep good backups.

Answer (score 3):

I think its because your RAM is faulty ;)

Answer (score 2):

Rapid BIOS boot only performs a very limited number of hardware tests. By disabling it, you have allowed the BIOS to perform all of the tests (POST) which would include a more thorough testing of your memory. You now need to look into sorting out your memory fault before you attempt to install an OS.